# How to get current value from PyQt comboBox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am using PyQt designer and then converting it using pyuic4.
My ui file has this comboBox that looks like this:

```
    self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self.groupBox_3)
    self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 81, 22))
    self.comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox"))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
```

so as you can see, the text that i put in my combo box doesnt show up in this part of the code, however it does show up in the gui.

usually when I have some user selection, like a radio button, I can do this check:

```
if self.RAnkle.isChecked():
```

i can do similar things with input text.  I am trying to do this logic with the comboBox, like I want to say self.comboBox.getText()  and return the string that the user has selected.  I tried doing some items on this http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html  but i cant get it to work.

For example, this code:

```
self.comboBox.activated()
```

Returns this error message:

```
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

I have also tried to use the itemData() but i still receive an error:

```
TypeError: QComboBox.itemData(int, int role=Qt.UserRole): not enough arguments
```

I am doing this inside of the callback, so i first do this:

```
self.analyzeButton.clicked.connect(self._AnalyzeData)
```

Then inside the function _AnalyzeData I am trying to get the text of the current combobox item.

so, is this possible?

thanks

Comment: so the answer to the questions is the .currentText() but It would be nice if someone could explain the reasoning for the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, about your errors, aren't they pretty self-explanatory ? :-)

From the documentation you just linked :

> void activated (int)
>
> This is the default overload of this signal.This signal is sent when
>   the user chooses an item in the combobox. The item's index is passed.
>   Note that this signal is sent even when the choice is not changed. If
>   you need to know when the choice actually changes, use signal
>   currentIndexChanged().

As a Qt signal it cannot directly be called: it can be emitted, and you can create a slot that will be called when it happens.

> QVariant QComboBox.itemData (self, int index, int role = Qt.UserRole)
>
> Returns the data for the given role in the given index in the
>   combobox, or QVariant.Invalid if there is no data for this role.
>
> See also setItemData().

The role parameter has a default value so you can omit it, but you have to give the index.

Glad you found the solution anyway !

Comment: okay so i found a solution, but it wasnt actually what I was trying to do, and i just realized it haha.  I was trying to say, if i have a combobox with values, how can I query if a specific value is selected by just using its name, or do i need to know the index of the name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a `SLOT` in `connect function` with argument passing you should using lambda such as :

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), 
                               lambda: self.materialsInstance.setFilterDict_Insert("L",self,"name",self.lineEdit.text()))
```